# I have an excel file that uses the VLOOKUP formula but in order to work I must doubleclick each cell

Tags: excel

Yes in order to work all cells must be as text. I've selected all them and formated as text but VLOOKUP doesn't work. To work I must double-click every single cell.

It's there anyway faster to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table A is from the database. The col that I'm looking for is set to text somehow (but is not manually done.)

In the table B which is manual I put some numbers (and sometimes chars) that act as id.

Now I want data from table A to show up in table B. I use vlookup but it doesn't work, because it says it can't find.

Now I select all cells from table A and format them as text. But vlookup still doesn't work.

Now if I double click on a cell it will convert somehow to real text and vlookup works, but this takes a long time if you have many rows.

So the solution is to append an empty string to the cell like this: B1&"", where B1 is the id of the cell in the excel.

Comment: Are you sure it is not your autocalculation that is turned off. To be honest, I don't understand your own answer about =B2&"" in the context of automatically recalculating vloopkups (vlookup is always calculated automatically, this is what can make some sheets slow, unless you turn automatic calculations off).

Comment: well. The table is returned from the db and the column I look up is set as text somehow. In my column (not from db) is also set manually to text but excel still consider it as number. By appending an empty string &"" to the cell it will convert to real text for vlookup to work.

Comment: OK, I see, I sometimes have to do the opposite, =B2*1 to turn them into real numbers.